# DOM Manipulation using javascript hangs the UI thread

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a page that shows two drop downs, one for subject, and other for courses as like this

```
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Subject:</legend>
        <select id="subjectList" onchange="SetCourses()">
             <option value="">select subject</option>
             <option value="1">Html</option>
             <option value="2">Css</option>
             <option value="3">Javascript</option>
             <option value="4">Jquery</option>
             <option value="5">Php</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Courses:</legend>
        <select id="courseList">
             <option value="">select course</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
```

So with change of subject, the course drop down refresh with a huge list of courses (around 9000 - 10000 records) as like this

```
    function SetCourses() {
        var subject = $('#subjectList').val();
        var courseList = $('#courseList');
        var courseString = '<option value="">select course</option>';
        if (!!subject) {
            courseList.html(courseString);
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
               url: "test.html",
               context: document.body
            }).done(function(data) {
               if(!!data) {
                  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                     courseString += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.text+'</option>'; 
                  });
                  courseList.html(courseString);   // this takes times 
               }
            });
        }
    }
```

Problem is that when the records are written to the course drop down, it takes nearly 10-12 sec and for that time page gets hang, and if in between that time you just get to click somewhere, then browser gets unresponsive for a longer period of time.

I have gone through debugging and found that till the success of ajax call the page is perfect and when it reaches the line to write the data, from that time its freeze the UI.

So whats the proper way to write such a huge data to DOM without freezing the UI?

Comment: That seems to be a rather excessive amount of data for a `<select>`. Is there a reason to load that many?

Answer (score 3):

I think for a list that long a drop down is inappropriate, try an auto complete: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ I don't think any user is going to browse through 9 to 10 thousand items to find the course they're interested in.

As for the lagging; there are limits of what you can do and this is the limit. I don't see an easy optimize that'll fix it and it would be pointless to do so since nobody is going to use a dropdown containing thousands of items.

Would you?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, you are right, this will be really not a good UI, although the client itself wants in this way. I had used that "autocomplete" way, but need to remove as client needed in this way. Already had a much discussion regarding this with them, but they thought this will be helpful for them as they are going to integrate this in some other stuffs. Is their some other way, i can achieve this?

Comment: I agree that a select with that many items is basically unusable. Auto-complete or a list with live filtering are much better UI, but you may want to look into something other than string concatenation: http://jsperf.com/string-concat-vs-array-join-10000/8

Comment: @AshisKumar You could have a look at documentfragment and use that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment

Comment: @AshisKumar Here is a better example, you create an element and append it to the document fragment, when you're done you append the document fragment to the DOM. I think it'll take a long time too because a dropdown isn't designed to contain thousands of items. Just like trying to set the text of a textarea to 25mb of text. These things will "crash" the browser or at a minimum make it unresponsive. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment

Comment: @HMR Thanks for the example. Looks like its really worse than i thought. Hope, i need to convince my client regarding these stuffs. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the user in mind. Populating dropdown with thousands of items is not a good user interface design.

Change your code and construct the whole string aside in memory and add it to the page after it is finished.

Edit: After I started to edit your code sample I sorted all the parenhesis and braces Irealized that your code already contains what i suggested.
You may try to create DOM objects directly without string intermediate as HMR suggests in his comment.

Comment: Yes its not a good practice unless i have to do this :(. Please can you share the code snippet to do this?